# invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ on very simple code?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char* x=    'x';
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this simple code give this error?

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  char* x= 'x';
```

Is it possible to have a pointer pointing to a an address holding a single character literal? Am I even asking that question right?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this simple code give this error?

Because C++ doesn't allow a conversion from `char` to `char*`. That is what the cryptic error message means.

> Is it possible to have a pointer pointing to a an address holding a single character literal?

No, C++ doesn't allow to take the address of an rvalue (but some compilers might offer that as an "extension"). But you can take the address of a `char` lvalue. For example,

```
char x = 'x';
char* p = &x; // pointer to a single char. NOT a null terminated string.
```

> Am I even asking that question right?

No.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you store 'x' somewhere, you can't take it's address and assign it to a char* pointer.

```
char _x = 'x';
char* x = &_x;
```

This would be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration says that the variable (x) is a pointer to char.  Pointers are a reference to a memory location.  You are then trying to assign a character 'x' to a pointer variable.  The compiler is complaining that you are trying to assign two unlike things.  Like old woman = frog, it just doesn't make sense.

What is more likely what you want is something on the order of:

```
char x = 'x';
```

Which says, assign the character variable x the ascii value of the literal letter 'x'.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make 'x' a variable first.